# Javascript react component conditional menu item showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component and I've added 2 links.

One link will show the login link and the other with show the logout.

I just don't want both to show so on componentDidMount I've added a condition which will hide either one or the other.

Here is the code:

```
class Navigation extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    let logged = true;

    if (logged) {
      document.getElementById('login').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('logout').style.display = 'none';
    }

    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li id="login"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
          <li id="logout"><a href="#logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

The issue is not nothing is being hidden either way so it's not working.

How can I fix this so I can get the condition to hide either one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say instead of directly modifying the `DOM properties` go with the React approach of conditional rendering like

```
class Navigation extends Component {

  render() {
    //Get the logged value from wherever you are getting it in the application.
    // Eg: let logged = true 
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {logged ? (<li id="logout"><a href="#logout">Logout</a></li>) :  (<li id="login"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>) }

        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to pass the `logged` variable to the `Navigation` component simply as props: `<Navigation logged />`. In that case, you could than write it this way:

```
const Navigation = ({ logged }) => {
  <div>
    <ul>
      {!logged && <li id="login"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>}
      {logged && <li id="logout"><a href="#logout">Logout</a></li>}
    </ul>
  </div>
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the style `display: none` and manipulating the `DOM` directly, use [conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) and render only one element on the basis of condition. Use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) applying conditions inside `JSX`.

Like this:

```js
class Navigation extends React.Component {

    render() {
        let logged = true;     //use actual value
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {
                        logged ? 
                            <li id="logout"><a href="#logout">Logout</a></li>
                        :
                            <li id="login"><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Navigation/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```